# File name storage in a variable

Tags: r

I would like to know if it is possible to store, in a variable, the name of the file I would like to read using read.delim() function. In other words: 
what I do is:

> ```
>    x=read.delim("myfile.txt", header = T)
> ```

I would like to store in a variable, for example, y, the name of the file "myfile". I used the 
list.files() function but since I have around 1000 files in my folder I need to store for each file each specific name.

Can anyone help me please?

Best

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why is `list.files` relevant? `y <- "myfile.txt"; x <- read.delim(y, header = TRUE)`?

Comment: Did you try it? Did something not work? It should work nicely with `list.files` so you dont need to manually type filenames.

Comment: what about `l_files<-list.files();invisible(sapply(l_files,function(name) assign(name,name,envir=.GlobalEnv)))` ? Although this will get you 1000 variables in your global envir if you have 1000 files so you should just go with l_files...

Comment: What I meant was something like `files <- list.files(pattern = ".\\.txt$")` and then `mydata <- lapply(files, read.delim)` to read in all the txt files from your directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if it is possible to store, in a variable, the
>   name of the file I would like to read using read.delim() function

Yes, that's possible.

> I used the list.files() function but since I have around 1000 files in
>   my folder I need to store for each file each specific name.

If you have 1000 files that you want to read into R, it's a very good idea to use the `list.files` function that you already mentioned in your question. You can read in all the file names in your directory (which fulfill a certain pattern if you like) and then you can easily use those file names, stored in a variable, to read them all into your R session, for example using `lapply` so that you will end up with only a single new object which will be a list containing several (e.g. 1000) data frames. To do that, as I commented, you can use:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".\\.txt$")
mydata <- lapply(files, read.delim, header = TRUE)
```

`mydata` is now a list containing all the txt files in your current working directory and each file is an element in your list.